# Создание формы в ООП и добавление стилей

Tags: php, html, css, ооп

Не много опыта в ООП,только его вот начинаю изучать. Не могу никак понять как это должно работать.Есть класс,я его реализую через интерфейс,в поле задаю значение HTML тега input и вывожу его через функцию show().Но,нужно добавить ко всему этому еще и стили,к самой форме.Сколько не пробовал,ничего не выходит.Прилагаю попытки этого кода.Прошу помощи,спасибо за внимание!

```
interface Input {

    public function show();
    public function addStyles(array $style);

}


class InputEmail implements Input {
private $label = "Ввод адреса";
private $_html = "<input type= email name=  email>";

    function show() {
     $this->_html ;
    echo $this->label;
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
    }


public function addStyles(array $style) {
    foreach($style as $key => $value) {
     
      $styles .= $key."form".$value."form-control";
    }

    // Теперь просто создаем input сразу со стилями с атрибутом style
    $this->_html = "<input type= 'email' style='".$styles."'>";
}



}








$style =['color'=> 'red', 'font-size'=> '15px'];



interface Input {

    public function show();
    public function addStyles(array $style);

}


class InputEmail implements Input {
private $label = "Ввод адреса";
private $_html = "<input type= email name=  email>";

    public function show() {

    return $this->_html ." " . $this->label ;

    echo"<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
    }


public function addStyles(array $style) {
    $this->_html = '<input type="email" style=;"'. join(' ', $style).'">';;
}


function showHtml(){
    return $this->_html;
}



}
$class = new InputEmail();
$class->addStyles(['color'=> 'red' , 'font-size'=> '15px']);
echo $class->showHtml();
```

Comment: что там внутри $style? если просто список имен стилей, то проще склеить так $this->_html = '<input type="email" style="'. join(' ', $style).'">';

Comment: пример https://onlinegdb.com/wtTFSxXAv echo старайся не делать в функциях, функция должна что-то возвращать, чтобы потом не было путаницы.

Comment: стыдно спросить,как добавить к массиву $style список стилей?  $style[] = а тут что?Линк на стили?

Comment: нифига не понял из последнего коммента

Comment: Вы мне ответили "что там внутри $style? если просто список имен стилей". Я из этого понял,что он у меня путсой,возможно это и служило проблемой с самого начала.Но,как в него,добавить,как Вы говорите список имен стилей? мол $style  =["color"=>"red" ],вроде этого? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: да, это я и спрашивал, что внутри $style. Массивом и добавляй

Comment: Вот я попробовал сделать для формы скругления $style =['padding'=>'10px','border-radius'=>'10px']; Но оно почему-то не отображается.Видимо нужно подключить к странице css, но,то что я прописал ранее  echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>"; - не будет работать?

Comment: стили пропиши внутри style.css, а в хтмл коде страницы обычно добавляют классы